# ThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes Java 8 alternative?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In java 11 and up there's MXBeans.getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes to get allocation information per thread, but this API isn't available in Java 8.

Is there any other way (without triggering a heap dump) I can get the allocation statistics per thread in Java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadAllocatedBytes())

> This is a convenience method for local management use and is equivalent to calling:
> `getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());`

The [linked method `getThreadAllocatedBytes​(long id)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getThreadAllocatedBytes(long)) does already exists in Java 8. Since `com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean` is a non-standard extension to `java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean` you may invoke the method dynamically, to avoid a hard-coded dependency:

```java
try {
  long bytes = (Long)ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
     .invoke(new ObjectName("java.lang:type=Threading"), "getThreadAllocatedBytes",
         new Object[] { Thread.currentThread().getId() }, new String[] { "long" });
  System.out.println(bytes);
} catch(JMException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

But if you use a build tool that doesn’t enforce restrictions, to use the official API only, the following would also work with Java 8 and the reference implementation:

```java
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import com.sun.management.ThreadMXBean;

public class MxTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadMXBean tmxb = (ThreadMXBean)ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long bytes = tmxb.getThreadAllocatedBytes(Thread.currentThread().getId());
    System.out.println(bytes);
  }
}
```

Note that there is a small possibility of failure due to the fact that `getId()` is not `final` and hence, a subclass of `Thread` could override it and return whatever it wants. That’s why JDK 19 has deprecated it and added a new `final` method `threadId()`. But in Java 8, you have to go with `getId()`. Just be aware of this possibility which hopefully never occurs.